# Foundation 6.3 $wrapper.css JS issue

Tags: javascript

I seem to be having a JS conflict with Foundation 6.3, and can't seem to figure out why it is.  Here is a screen shot of the error:

http://prntscr.com/e717nk

Seems to be an issue finding the variable $wrapper.css, but I am unsure why it is even looking for it? I am using F6.3, and the foundation.min.js file.

Any suggestions here?

Thanks,

Aaron

Comment: For future questions. Try and post snippets of code rather then just an image. Image's are harder to work with and troubleshoot then actual code.

Comment: Oops, sorry... new to this...TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.$wrapper.css'), this is the error I am getting. When expanded, I get:             key: "_resize",
            value: function() {
                this.$wrapper.css({
                    "max-width": "none",
                    "min-height": "none"
                }), this.$wrapper.css(this._getMaxDims())
            }.  this is directly from the foundation.min.js file

Answer (score 0):

In the foundation code. $wrapper gets initialized like this:

```
...
this.$wrapper = this.$element.find('.' + this.options.containerClass);
...
```

`this.options.containerClass` gets set to either "orbit-container" or "sticky-container" depending on the context of what component you're using.

It could be that you are missing one of these required classes on one of your components.

Comment: Thanks - I'll check it out! and advise.